# How to connect code base for a team of developers working on a project running on a VPS?

Tags: php, angularjs, git, macos, server

What is the best way to connect a team of  developers working on a project which runs on a VPS, We have Mac and windows development Environement and VPS is Based on CENT OS?

- I am totally newbie at creating a shared codebase.
- I am laravel, ionic, javascript, angular and node developer.
- The ease of doing this is nearly zero when we have to continuously change code and multiple people have to update different script files on the Project from Mac and Windows development environment.
- We use the later described technology, we want to connect to the servers and the code that is written should reflect on the servers. Right now we have to copy all the code and than paste it on the servers?

Should we go for SVN or GIT, and how to execute the Shared code base Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Develop locally

You definitely have to go with git to synchronize your code between all developers.

Git will ease most of the synchronization / merging work. All you have to do is to get familiar with it and its workflow. I know it can seem a lot at first but since every company is using it, it's not a waste of time.

Each developer works on his own machine (localhost) and commits / pushes to git when it's working properly. Other developers pull the changes to get new updates from the other developers on the team.

Don't shy away from using [branch system](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to work simultaneously on different features / part of you app and pull requests to review code of other developers.

Worry about deploying to the VPS later: setup your git repository ([github](https://github.com/), [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)) and work locally.

### Deploy later

Then, once you've reached a working version of your app/website, you can push your code to the VPS server [using git as well](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) and make it available to all for testing. You have to have SSH access on it.